# geom_ribbon set slope & intercept

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've created the following plot with ggplot using this code:

[image]

The dashed line is my model and the solid line is a reference line generated with:

```
geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0)
```

I'd like to add a ribbon around my reference line with slopes that range form 0.9 to 1.1 (intercept still remains at 0). Can someone provide me with an example for how to code this?

Comment: How about like this: `geom_ribbon(aes(x,ymin=0+.9*x, ymax=0+1.1*x), fill="black",alpha=.2)`?

Comment: Thanks.  This looks quite nice.  One other quick question - is there a way to extend the ribbon to the edges of the plot?

Comment: You might need to create a separate data set if you want the ribbon to extend across the whole range of your plot. Maybe `df2 <- data.frame(x = seq(-80,0))`, and then specify `data=df2` in `geom_ribbon()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be an overkill, but my solution would be - draw multiple ablines in the background with different slopes.

```
# Generate dummy model data
dModel <- data.frame(x = 5:10, y = sqrt(5:10))

# Plot data
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dModel) + 
    # Model
    geom_line(aes(x, y), linetype = 2) +
    # This will be ribbon - multiple lines with different slopes
    geom_abline(slope = seq(0.9, 1.1, 0.001), color = "grey60", intercept = 0) +
    geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1, 10), xlim = c(1, 10)) +
    theme_classic()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I never would have through to just plot multiple sequential ablines!  This worked quite neatly, although I need to find a way to make the lines semi-transparent because they obscure several of my data points.

Comment: @user3220999 try setting alpha for abline (`alpha = 0.1`)

Comment: @user3220999 is there any way I can improve my question so you would accept it?

Comment: Sorry! I was away for a few weeks and am just getting caught up on stuff now.  Thanks for your help!